# Why does the selected attribute move to a different option when I sort

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script here that takes the options in a select drop down and orders them alphabetically. However when I run the script and view it in Firebug I can see that the selected attribute moves to a different option.
Here is a jsbin I made http://jsbin.com/guhoyede/2/

```
  <select name="test" id="test">
    <option value="three">Dropkick Murphys</option>
    <option value="one">AC DC</option>
    <option value="four">Metallica</option>
    <option value="two" selected>Bruce Dickinson</option>
    <option value="ADD_NEW">Add New Item...</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="change">Change</button>
```

```
$('#change').click(function(){

  var options = $('#test option');

  var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { 
    return { 
      t: $(o).text(), 
      v: o.value 
    }; 
  }).get();

  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { 
    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; 
  });

  options.each(function(i, o) {
    o.value = arr[i].v;
    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
  });

  $('#test option[value="ADD_NEW"]').appendTo($('#test'));

});
```

Comment: I'd say it's because you're not sorting the actual options, you're retrieving the key / value combinations, sorting those, then applying those to the existing options, losing the "Selected" property in the process.

Comment: Well it seems to sort the options alphabetically but the selected then moves up the list each time i click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort `option` elements and append them to select to reorder. It will preserve `selected` property:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('#test option').sort(function(o1, o2) { 
        return o1.text.localeCompare(o2.text); 
    }).appendTo('#test');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/guhoyede/7/edit

UPD for Firefox:

```
$('#change').click(function() {

    var $select = $('#test'),
        $options = $select.find('option').sort(function(o1, o2) { 
            return o1.label.localeCompare(o2.label); 
        });

    $options.each(function() {
        $select.append(this);
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/guhoyede/12/edit

Comment: It works in chrome but for some reason firefox switches the select to the last option. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Found this article. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958934#c7 FF say the reason it works in Chrome and IE is because it is a bug in those browsers

Comment: Funny. Yes, that's why using `$options.each(...)` to append items works fine.